# How to show interactive character limits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

How does Stack Overflow show interactive character limits? Like when editing comments, it shows you how many characters you have left, as well as warning if it is too few.

I'd like that exact functionality in my Ruby on Rails... But not sure how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, only available in COBOL.Net

Comment: ..and why the php tag is there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following JavaScript function to restrict max length in textareas

```
function checkLength(edit, maxlen) 
{
if (edit.value.length > maxlen) 
    edit.value = edit.value.substring(0, maxlen);

    document.getElementById('remaining').innerHTML = edit.value.length;
}
```

Link this to your textarea's onKeyDown and onKeyUp attributes:

```
onKeyDown = "checkLength(this, 100);"
```

Answer (score 12):

Stackoverflow uses the [jQuery JavaScript Framework](http://jquery.com/) and it has a lot of existing scripts and plugins for this sort of thing.

One example is this [Interactive Character Limit for TextArea in jQuery](http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2007/11/09/interactive-character-limit-for-textarea-using-jquery/) demonstrated [here](http://www.ajaxray.com/Examples/charLimit.html).

I'm sure there are others as well.

Comment: I've been trying to get the TextArea without the Jquery to work...challenges with it....

Comment: @Angela, is there a reason you don't want to use jQuery?  It helps solve browser compatibility issues.

Comment: @Angela, if you insist on ~not~ using a javascript framework, then I suggest asking a new question asking how to do it in raw javascript.

Answer (score 1):

by using the onkeydown event on the input. There are millions of examples out there and frankly I'd be surprised if this isn't a duplicate question.

It is: [How to show interactive character limits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823575/how-does-stack-overflow-show-interactive-character-limits)

Comment: You linked to the same question!  It is a duplicate of ... itself?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for some javascript, basically you add a handler to the textbox onkeypress event then to get the current length:

```
mytextbox.value.length
```

and to limit it you could do something like:

```
if (mytextbox.value.length > maxlimit) 
mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple javascript event handling to show character counts
for input elements.  No server side processing required.

This javascript catches the key-press event for a text area "txt"
and shows the character count in a span "count".

See it running at 

http://aaron.oirt.rutgers.edu/myapp/root/charCount.html

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function go() {
    var txt=document.getElementById("txt");
    txt.onkeydown = countTxt;
}
function countTxt() {
    var txt=document.getElementById("txt");
    var count=document.getElementById("count");
    count.innerHTML = txt.value.length+1; // count the character not shown yet ;)
}
</script>

</head>
<body onload="go()">

<h3>type in the text area and see the count change</h3>

<textarea id="txt" rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
<br>
count: <span id="count"> 0</span>

</body>
```

The count can be off my +-1 -- fixing that (if you really want to) is left to the reader.